# Unable to set gain in Mindvision camera

Tags: c++, opencv, camera

The Mindvision camera application shows gain can be set in float. When I try to set the gain programmatically, the function call only provides an option to set the gain in an integer.

The following call is available in the file CamerApi.h

MVSDK_API CameraSdkStatus __stdcall CameraSetGain(
CameraHandle    hCamera,
int             iRGain,
int             iGGain,
int             iBGain
);

I am using the VC++ examples to run the application.
Any option to set the gain in floating value?

Comment: Make sure that `int` gain variables aren't being interpreted as [fixed-point values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic). You might only be allowed to input `int`s but those `int`s could be counting in, for example, tenths.

Comment: @user4581301 : Thanks for highlighting this. After going through the documentation of the API file, I found integer values are further divided by 100 internally, making it float.